# On a ggplot, I am using Preserve='single' to make the bars the same length, but this messes the whole graph up. How can I fix this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The idea behind this df and plot is to group "User Experience Framework" into "Customer Journey Area". Then, I separate these groupings out into a count of the positive occurrences vs a count of the negative occurrences and plot them on a ggplot bar graph. This graph looks perfect EXCEPT, the bars are different widths. I try to fix this with Preserve='single', but it messes the whole graph up. I'll be forever grateful if anyone can solve this....

Here is the head(df):

```
> head(df,30)
          Journey.Area Experience.Framework Postive.or.Negative
1           Installing     People/Associate                   1
2        Using Product            Execution                  -1
3           Installing     People/Associate                   1
4             Delivery            Execution                  -1
5           Installing     People/Associate                  -1
6             Delivery     People/Associate                   1
7           Installing            Execution                  -1
8        Using Product            Execution                  -1
9             Browsing     People/Associate                  -1
10            Browsing     People/Associate                  -1
11            Browsing     People/Associate                   1
12              Buying              Systems                  -1
13            Delivery            Execution                  -1
14            Delivery     People/Associate                   1
15          Installing            Execution                  -1
16 Deciding How to Buy       Process/Policy                   1
17          Installing     People/Associate                  -1
18          Installing     People/Associate                   1
19            Delivery            Execution                  -1
20              Buying       Process/Policy                   1
21            Delivery            Execution                  -1
22          Installing            Execution                   1
23            Browsing     People/Associate                   1
24          Installing            Execution                  -1
25            Delivery            Execution                  -1
26          Installing            Execution                  -1
27          Installing            Execution                  -1
28 Deciding How to Buy       Process/Policy                  -1
29          Installing            Execution                  -1
30            Browsing              Systems                  -1
```

Here is the code for my current graph. Groupings are created based on Journey Area and the count of each Experience Framework is shown on the graph. Positive groupings go to the right and negative to the left.

```
df %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
    mutate(Journey.Area = factor(Journey.Area, 
                               levels = c("Getting Assistance", "Returning", "Using Product", "Installing", 
                                          "Delivery", "Pickup", "Anticipating", "Buying", 
                                          "Deciding How to Buy", "Browsing"))) %>%
  summarise(score = n() * Postive.or.Negative) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = score, y = Journey.Area, fill = Experience.Framework)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), width = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-20, 20), labels = abs) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  labs(x = 'Negative Sentiment        Positive Sentiment', y="Customer Journey Area", fill="User Experience Framework") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12)) + ggtitle("Customer Sentiment Matrix") + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

Here is the graph output:
[image: Looks great except the bars are different widths]

Okay, So I now try to fix it with adding preserve='single':

```
df %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
    mutate(Journey.Area = factor(Journey.Area, 
                               levels = c("Getting Assistance", "Returning", "Using Product", "Installing", 
                                          "Delivery", "Pickup", "Anticipating", "Buying", 
                                          "Deciding How to Buy", "Browsing"))) %>%
  summarise(score = n() * Postive.or.Negative) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = score, y = Journey.Area, fill = Experience.Framework)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = 'single')) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-20, 20), labels = abs) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  labs(x = 'Negative Sentiment        Positive Sentiment', y="Customer Journey Area", fill="User Experience Framework") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12)) + ggtitle("Customer Sentiment Matrix") + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

And the result is that my groupings are now messed up? I am not sure how to resolve this....
[image: Bars are now individual counts instead of the grouping totals?]

Comment: You tryed to use position_dodge instead of position dodge2 ?

Comment: That's not it unfortunately. I have tried both ways :(

Comment: May i suggest another try?   take away the fill paramter from global ggplot and puit inside aes() in geom_col ggplot(aes(x = score, y = Journey.Area)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Experience.Framework), position = position_dodge(), width = 0.5)

Comment: When I do that, it plots like the original graph where the bars are different widths. Did it work for you? If so, could you share the full code you used?

Comment: What's wrong with your plot when you use `position_dodge(preserve = "single")` ? It gives me the expected result. Can you show what it gives you and explain why it's not what you want?